# how to send DataSet object to client

Tags: dataset

how to send a serialized DataSet object from server to client using streams socket

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to do that sort of thing is to use a `NetworkStream` and the `WriteXml()` method on your DataSet (assuming you have your socket set up and connected):

```
using( var networkStream = new NetworkStream(socket) )
{
    dataSet.WriteXml(networkStream);
}
```